# How to add a BizTalk Group to BizTalk Server

Tags: .net, biztalk

Currently I've started learning to work with BizTalk Server.
As I'm learning through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334500%28v=bts.80%29.aspx walk-through, I confront a problem where it says:

> 2: In the console tree on the left side of the BizTalk Server Administration Console, expand BizTalk Server Administration, right-click BizTalk Group, and then click Refresh.

In my console there is no group and I don't know how to add such group.

[image]

There just a `Connect to existing group` in the `Administration Console` which tries to connect to a database which I don't have it (Or I don't know how to create it).

**Question:** How can I create or have a BizTalk Group so I can continue this walk-through?

FYI: I'm using BizTalk Server 2013 (Evaluation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to setting up BizTalk server, installation and then configuration.

Seems like you have installed BizTalk Server, now you need to run BizTalk Configuration to create the databases, BizTalk Hosts and other things.

You can look through the documentation to get familiar with the process.  If you're just experimenting with development, you can use the express option with creates s BizTalk Group with all default settings.

MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248696(v=bts.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248696%28v=bts.80%29.aspx)

Comment: It really helps, but I couldn't find the express option!